# Is it possible to save some structure as sequence of bytes?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I am using a library that only allows to store arrays of `[u8]`, and I have a struct from external crate that *does not* implement `Serialize` and *does not* provide its fields (i. e. they are private). Question: is it possible to turn an instance of this struct into an array of `[u8]` without causing an undefined behaviour? I was pointed to the fact that simple `transmute` may cause undefined behaviour because structure may contain uninitialized data in the form of padding fields.

Comment: In the genral case it does not make sense  to be able to serialize an arbitrary struct. What if it contains a pointer to some memory location, a socket, a file handle, etc ?

Comment: The thing is, it does contain a pointer. But this "serialized" data is guaranteed to be stored for a smaller period of time than the pointer lives and stays on the same machine in the same process.

Comment: So you want to save the pointer ?

Comment: Yes. I want to serialize a structure with a pointer and store it in a temporary storage that only supports passing an array of bytes, and deserialize it back after.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: is it possible to turn an instance of this struct into an array of [u8] without causing an undefined behaviour?

You can always serialize it by hand (to whatever format you choose), especially if all sub-fields are serializable.

It's extremely risky and wildly unsafe if you're serializing a pointer and expecting it to come out fine the other way around, but your deserialization will make that rather clear I guess.

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear, but fields are private. Updated my question.

Comment: Then I'd say you're screwed, technically you can't *know* what's padding and what's not, and I don't think you can assume the behaviour of the builtin memcpy with respect to padding so you can't zero a buffer and tell rust to copy / move the struct *there*, as the undefs will propagate to that buffer and you won't be able to read the raw data (legally I mean).

Comment: (Repost because of wrong link) But will uninitialized data propagate if I use union as a buffer?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3bfce45ea3139d093af75f60e4667d7d

Comment: I would assume so, the value will be at least partially [`undef`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#undefined-values) and I don't see how type-punning through a union would change that. Though I do not know for sure, I'm not really steeped into unsafe. Miri is certainly very very cross with your program though, so that's a bad sign (you can find miri under "Tools" on the playgrounds).

Comment: Yeah... yeah, I was wrong, thanks. For sure, I am doomed.